# Send username/password to SOAP Service

Tags: apigee

I created a WDSL API-Proxy, everything works find but as expected i'm receiving an Authentication error because i'm not sending the correct user and password to the SOAP server, where do i set that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need pass username and password in header request.

Comment: Didn't realize had had to insert the soap enveloap in the assign message of the WSDL method, what a noob!

Answer (score 0):

Typical you will include an Authorization header for a SOAP call. I typically do these in an assign message policy like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<AssignMessage name="buildSoapMessage">
    <DisplayName>buildSoapMessage</DisplayName>
    <AssignTo createNew="true" type="request">request</AssignTo>
    <Set>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Authorization">{request.header.Authorization}</Header>
        </Headers>
        <Verb>POST</Verb>
        <Payload contentType="text/xml">
            <Request xmlns="urn:foo:bar:1.0">
```